# How to make an associative array in actionscript indexed by Point?

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, associative-array

I'd like my associative array indexed by `Point` (or, in general, an `Object`) that has a semantic equality. Unfortunately

```
var p:Point = new Point(1, 1);
var q:Point = new Point(1, 1);

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dict[p] = 5;
trace(dict[p]); // => 5
trace(dict[q]); // => undefined
```

because

```
trace(p===q); // => false
```

Is there any way to tell `Dictionary` how to order its keys, or is there a different class to use for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you use `Object`, it seems to work as intended:

```
var p:Point = new Point(1, 1);
var q:Point = new Point(1, 1);
var r:Point = new Point(1, 2);

var dict:Object = new Object();
dict[p] = 5;
trace(dict[p]); // => 5
trace(dict[q]); // => 5
trace(dict[r]); // => undefined
```

Comment: i haven't tried this, it's just a hunch, but are you *sure* this works? i suspect it might do a string conversion on p before using it as an index, so ALL points will collide.

Comment: I believe Object's keys are just strings, so any non-String object you use as a key will be converted to a string.  Object's toString() method returns the same thing regardless of its contents, so this most likely would not work.

Comment: aha. it works because points have a nice toString function that outputs the two values (x=1, y=2) so i guess it will work the way you want, though i'm not sure it's the prettiest of solutions ;)

Comment: So what *would* be the prettiest of solutions?

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` will place objects in different bins, even if they are "equal". If the two objects used as keys result in a collision on insertion, the Dictionary will simply use the next available bin to place the second object, because, as you said, `p!==q`. But using `Object` (which is still, in essence, a map) is different, it only checks if `p.equals(q)`.

Comment: Actually, the `Object` must *not* check `p==q`, since in this case, it's false! (but `p.equals(q)` is true)

Comment: could've sworn it returned true for me. meh, no biggie; shouldn't be using `==` anyway.